# Upscale the key frames while decoding!

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, keyframes, scale, decoding

I would like to apply some kind of super-resolution (SR) to the keyframes in an H.264 video. The SR process should target the keyframes and upscale them by a factor of 2.

For the past few days, I've been trying to see where can I hold the key frame, in the C src code, in order to scale it. I'm confused whether to apply the scaling in the parsing packet part, or in the decoding part.

I also don't know if upscaling the B & P frames would be enough to not damage the video frames.

I hope you guide me as there are no sufficient documentation about FFmpeg. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: Scaling and other pixel operations operate upon raster data i.e. decoded frames. So you to decode and encode again. I don't think this will turn out as you expect.

Comment: I don't actually want to encode again. I want to display the decoded upscaled frames only.

Comment: hemoali - I think what gyan is saying is that you have no other option.